# Bluetooth connection between EV3 brick and MacBook Pro fails after 2 seconds

Tags: ev3, programming, software, bluetooth, mac

As I was adviced, I searched for same questions before posting mine but although some are similar, I can't make their answer useful for my problem.

I have a Mindstorms EV3 Education brick and a MacBook Pro mid 2009, Yosemite OS.

I want to connect them through Bluetooth for downloading to the brick and run programs written in the official Lego Mindstorms Education software.

I turn on the brick and activate Bluetooth. When I turn on Bluetooth on my laptop the 'ZIGORETO' (my brick name) appears with 'Link' option. I press it and the brick's screens shows the acceptation's window, then the password's. I press OK in both (keeping password as '1234'). The laptop's Bluetooth screen says 'Not connected' but offers me an 'Options' button. When I press it, a code is asked for. I enter '1234' and press enter. Again, on my brick Bluetooth the connection acceptance's screen appears, and the password's. I accept both, and 'ZIGORETO' device (my brick) appears connected for 2 seconds in my laptop Bluetooth connections window... and 'Not connected' again.

I've tried this with WIFI on and off, with Lego's software open and close, with USB cable plugged and unplugged... but to no avail.

After one year I finally have the time to start with my Lego passion (quarantined in Spain too, take care!)... and learning about the robot and coding with the cable plugged in is quite tiresome... could anyone help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't help with General Suport for this sort of thing. The OP should contact customer service.